# Must I do something special in order to have sections with an NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I created a fresh project with a core data template. then I added a employee entity with a firstName string attribute, and populated the persistent store with 100 employees and lots of different first names.

In the RootViewController where the FRC is created, I set the sectionNameKeyPath like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"firstName" 
    cacheName:@"Root"];
```

However, I never see any sections or titles. Probably I must activate this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the data source methods return section information. Check that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns the proper number of sections and that `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` returns the proper titles.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Too much stuff in the forest ;)